# Splitting on \" in String

Tags: c#, csv, split

So I have this **CSV** file where it's contents are like so...

```
"Name","Age","Gender","City, State"
```

So far I've been successful at removing the double quotes everywhere - except for the first and last entries with the following code.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputReport))
{
    headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

This results in an array of strings with the contents of:

```
\"Name
Age
Gender
City, State\"
```

I've made several attempts to remove the `\"`

Including adding this to my split criteria:

```
String.Concat('\\','\"')
```

And this:

```
"\\\""
```

But nothing seems to work, I feel like I should be able to remove these in the Split method. It's kind of a tricky string to match. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are you seeing `\"`? I suspect you're seeing it in the debugger, which means the backslash isn't really there...

Comment: Because the every entry already is already double quotes - to preserve the commas inside individual entries.

Comment: He's splitting on ",". You could split on both " and \ and remove the empty entries, on use Regex.

Comment: Use [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) - it has the ability to handle quoted fields properly.

Comment: Well splitting on "\\" and "\"" seems to have worked, however, I'm going to heed the warning of Joel Coehoorn that `String.Split` is the wrong tool for the job and I will familiarize myself with the `TextFieldParser` class for parsing CSV files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Don't use `String.Split()` to read CSV data!*

There are too many edge cases. You've just hit the tip of the iceberg here. Also, it's much slower than it needs to be. You want a dedicated CSV parser. There's one built into the framework (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`), and there are several you can download and use, including [`FastCSV`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) and my own [`EasyCSV`](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/EasyCSV).

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I'm glad that I was told that this is considered bad practice before it became a bad habit. It's in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace by the way.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `s.Replace(@""",","~").Replace(@"""","~").Split('~');` where s is your string value of a csv line read.

Comment: RegEx is overkill for something like this, and completely inappropriate when it comes to parsing a CSV file, IMO.

Comment: @Tim: understand Tim, but my idea was to give working solution using similar approach which Derek was using, as he asked solution to get his current code/approach working. but yes should have suggested better option other than current approach. will follow this advise next time onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You may split by characters "(double qoute), '(Comma) and /(Slash). Try this:

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputReport))
        {
            char [] splitByCharSet = new char[3]{'\"', '\\', ','};
            headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(splitByCharSet, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
```